# Remove "help" tag

Tags: support, tags

I posted a question tagged with "help" but later edited and changed to "documentation".

Now nothing is tagged with "help", so it can be removed.

Answer (score 5):

Orphaned tags are removed automatically if they not used for a period of time. I believe that period is 24 hours, but don't quote me on that.